# How do I change the PATH variable for automatic CMake tests?

Tags: windows, cmake, automated-tests

I use the Cmake Testing feature with add_test but the executable does not find all dll's. Is there a way in CMake to set environment variables for theses tests?

I want to set something like:
PATH=%PATH%;C:\additional\lib\folder

Comment: What about `CTEST_ENVIRONMENT`? See [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Scripting_Of_CTest#More_Settings).

Comment: Thanks @Florian, your answer brought me to the following
[link](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2009-September/031900.html)
which has the answer how to set the environment within the CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

You can set the ENVIRONMENT property for every test. E.g. you can add after each add_test(...)

```
set_property(TEST testName PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT 
"PATH=%PATH%\;C:\\additional\\lib\\folder")
```

Take care that you escape \; and \

Answer (score 0):

If somebody uses catch2 with their function `catch_discover_tests(target [...])` then you can use DL_PATHS variable.

That's better, because it states to be cross-platform and helps to solve concatenations with `;` - i.e. semicolon delimiter problems with `PATH` on Windows.

[Docs:](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/cmake-integration.md#automatic-test-registration)

> `DL_PATHS path...`
> Specifies paths that need to be set for the dynamic linker to find shared
> libraries/DLLs when running the test executable (PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH respectively).
> These paths will both be set when retrieving the list of test cases from the
> test executable and when the tests are executed themselves. This requires
> cmake/ctest >= 3.22.

Example:

```
catch_discover_tests(Tests
    EXTRA_ARGS ${TEST_ARGS}
    DL_PATHS
        "/path/to/libdir/during/build/"
        "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:some_target>")
```